# Bitbucket git push ssh "conq: invalid repository syntax."

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket

**I cannot `git push` to my Bitbucket** for some reasons. It used to work but it do not work anymore and I can't figure why.

```
$ git push ssh://git@bitbucket.org:MyUser/MyGit.git
conq: invalid repository syntax.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I generated a ssh-key, added it to gitbucket. Identified my ssh-agent as such:

```
$ ssh-agent /bin/bash
$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
$ ssh-add -l
  #2048 14:41:6f:c9:06:54:88:6c:89:e2:ba:24:6c:36:10:78 /Users/SomeUser/.ssh/id_rsa (RSA)
```

Also checked my login

```
ssh -T git@bitbucket.org
logged in as MyUser.

You can use git or hg to connect to Bitbucket. Shell access is disabled.
```

Here are the details:

```
$ ssh -T -v git@bitbucket.org
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/vagrant/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to bitbucket.org [131.103.20.167] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH_5* compat 0x0c000000
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<3072<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 97:8c:2b:f4:6e:14:6b:5c:3b:zc:va:47:48:74:7c:40
debug1: Host 'bitbucket.org' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/vagrant/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Remote: Forced command: conq username:MyUser
debug1: Remote: Port forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: X11 forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Agent forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Pty allocation disabled.
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug1: Remote: Forced command: conq username:MyUser
debug1: Remote: Port forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: X11 forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Agent forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Pty allocation disabled.
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to bitbucket.org ([131.103.20.167]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LC_ALL = en_US.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
logged in as MyUser.

You can use git or hg to connect to Bitbucket. Shell access is disabled.
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Transferred: sent 3752, received 3400 bytes, in 0.1 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 61887.6, received 56081.5
debug1: Exit status 0
```

My `git remote -v`

```
$ git remote -v
MyGit   git@bitbucket-MyGit:MyUser/MyGit (fetch)
MyGit   git@bitbucket-MyGit:MyUser/MyGit (push)
```

My `~/.ssh/config`

```
Host bitbucket-MyGit
  HostName bitbucket.org
  User git
  IdentityFile /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_rsa
  IdentitiesOnly yes
```

I have looked around but I can't find what I have done wrong. Any suggestion?

Comment: What do you have set for your remotes in that repo? `git remote -v`

Comment: @Donal I have made the edit to include this information

Comment: I would have expected your remote to look like this: ssh://git@bitbucket.org/MyUser/MyGit.git

Comment: @Donal Actually, you are right, I just realized it at the same time. Waste so much time on this. Thank you!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This is incorrect

```
$ git push ssh://git@bitbucket.org:MyUser/MyGit.git
```

**This is correct**

```
$ git push ssh://git@bitbucket.org/MyUser/MyGit.git
```

Comment: it is weird that their auto-generated url on the site doesn't have the syntax correct :S :(

Comment: Their documentation is aggravating

Comment: omg - was about to lose my sh** on Bitbucket. Thank you SO much!

Comment: Is there anywhere on Bitbucket you can copy and paste this, like on Github? Can't find it anywhere

Comment: Solved my issue.